# MySQL InnoDB recovering from backup

Tags: database, innodb, recovery, windows-server, mysql

Recently my server crushed to the ground, but luckily I had full backup of the server's drive. My server is running Windows server 2008 and Plesk 9.5.

In order to restore my database, I followed the instructions: replace all `ib_logfile0`, `ib_logfile1`, `ibdata1` and add the `.frm`s/`.MYI`/`.MYD`.

The files has been replaced, and mysql was restarted. I've got the following error:

```
InnoDB: Error: log file .\ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 10489229 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 10485760 bytes!
121206 19:53:26 [ERROR] Default storage engine (InnoDB) is not available
121206 19:53:26 [ERROR] Aborting
121206 19:53:26 [Note] C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Databases\MySQL\bin\mysqld-nt.exe: Shutdown complete
```

The `my.ini` file has the following options:

```
[client]
port=3306

[mysql]
default-character-set=latin1

[mysqld]
port=3306
basedir="C:/Program Files (x86)/Parallels/Plesk/Databases/MySQL/"
datadir="C:/Program Files (x86)/Parallels/Plesk/Databases/MySQL/Data/"
default-character-set=latin1
default-storage-engine=INNODB
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
max_connections=100
query_cache_size=0
table_cache=256
tmp_table_size=35M
thread_cache_size=8
myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G
myisam_max_extra_sort_file_size=100G
myisam_sort_buffer_size=69M
key_buffer_size=55M
read_buffer_size=64K
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K
sort_buffer_size=256K
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=3M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_log_buffer_size=2M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=107M
innodb_log_file_size=10489229
innodb_thread_concurrency=10
```

Please help me, I've been trying different methods since last weeks and has devoted around 25 hours to it, your help will be fully welcomed!

I'm sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

The InnoDB log file has a different but similar size (read the error output!). InnoDB won't start with such a discrepancy. Your options:

- Edit the `my.cnf` file to match the current (reported) size. If the log file is corrupt in some way, this is a bad thing to do.
- Remove the `iblog` files and let InnoDB recreate them at the start of MySQL. You may loose some data if you took a snapshot when running the backup.